# Use user's computer as a proxy for cURL

Tags: php, proxy, curl

I am making an application that fetches some data via cURL, it logs in to a site and fetches statistics of a user.

But my problem is, that cURL uses the IP of my server, so if I get more than 1 user, every account that logs in will get banned.

I had 2 possible solutions, 1 being let the user install a webserver himself, but I don't really like that. The second possibility would be to use the IP address of my customer to log in.

In cURL this would be done using a proxy, but my question was, is it possible to somehow use the user's IP as a proxy for cURL?

Maybe with some kind of software installed?

Comment: So the curl process is running on your server? And you want to use the user's computer as a proxy for that? No, that's not going to work. Why can't the user's browser just request the data directly?

Comment: Additionally, why are you banning on IP? Surely you have some sort of API key - why not just ban API keys that are behaving badly.

Comment: I'm not banning on IP, the site I login to bans all accounts with the same IP. I cannot use API keys since they don't have an API.

Comment: Isnt it possible to use a users PC using special software that already exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with ajax. The client can do the requests directly and you will not need to use curl for it.

The easiest way doing it would be using jQuery - [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) you can get more information on jQuery ajax method.

Comment: Well no,because the site requires login too so I have to login with curl.

Comment: Two options: You can send the ajax request to the server you open with curl, and than, pass exactly that return data to your server.

Or, you can do that with a native application, like c++ - but this would be moreless the same, so i would take the first option.